# Actionscript 2.0 JSON-parser

Tags: flash, actionscript

I have the following code:

```
import JSON;
var products = JSON.parse('{"employees":[{"firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe"},        {"firstName":"Anna","lastName":"Smith"},{"firstName":"Peter","lastName":"Jones"}]}');
trace(products.employees[0].firstName);
```

Now, my trace return "undefined". Why?
I am using this code for parsing the actual parsing (not mine):

```
/*
Copyright (c) 2005 JSON.org

Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:

The Software shall be used for Good, not Evil.

THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE
SOFTWARE.
*/

/*
ported to Actionscript May 2005 by Trannie Carter <tranniec@designvox.com>, wwww.designvox.com
USAGE:
    try {
        var o:Object = JSON.parse(jsonStr);
        var s:String = JSON.stringify(obj);
    } catch(ex) {
        trace(ex.name + ":" + ex.message + ":" + ex.at + ":" + ex.text);
    }

*/

class JSON {

    static function stringify(arg):String {

                var c, i, l, s = '', v;

                switch (typeof arg) {
                case 'object':
                        if (arg) {
                                if (arg instanceof Array) {
                                        for (i = 0; i < arg.length; ++i) {
                                                v = stringify(arg[i]);
                                                if (s) {
                                                        s += ',';
                                                }
                                                s += v;
                                        }
                                        return '[' + s + ']';
                                } else if (typeof arg.toString != 'undefined') {
                                        for (i in arg) {
                                                v = arg[i];
                                                if (typeof v != 'undefined' && typeof v != 'function') {
                                                        v = stringify(v);
                                                        if (s) {
                                                                s += ',';
                                                        }
                                                        s += stringify(i) + ':' + v;
                                                }
                                        }
                                        return '{' + s + '}';
                                }
                        }
                        return 'null';
                case 'number':
                        return isFinite(arg) ? String(arg) : 'null';
                case 'string':
                        l = arg.length;
                        s = '"';
                        for (i = 0; i < l; i += 1) {
                                c = arg.charAt(i);
                                if (c >= ' ') {
                                        if (c == '\\' || c == '"') {
                                                s += '\\';
                                        }
                                        s += c;
                                } else {
                                        switch (c) {
                                                case '\b':
                                                        s += '\\b';
                                                        break;
                                                case '\f':
                                                        s += '\\f';
                                                        break;
                                                case '\n':
                                                        s += '\\n';
                                                        break;
                                                case '\r':
                                                        s += '\\r';
                                                        break;
                                                case '\t':
                                                        s += '\\t';
                                                        break;
                                                default:
                                                        c = c.charCodeAt();
                                                        s += '\\u00' + Math.floor(c / 16).toString(16) +
                                                                (c % 16).toString(16);
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                        return s + '"';
                case 'boolean':
                        return String(arg);
                default:
                        return 'null';
                }
        }

    static function parse(text:String):Object {
                var at = 0;
                var ch = ' ';
        var _value:Function;

                var _error:Function = function (m) {
                        throw {
                                name: 'JSONError',
                                message: m,
                                at: at - 1,
                                text: text
                        };
                }

                var _next:Function = function() {
                        ch = text.charAt(at);
                        at += 1;
                        return ch;
                }

                var _white:Function = function() {
                        while (ch) {
                                if (ch <= ' ') {
                                        _next();
                                } else if (ch == '/') {
                                        switch (_next()) {
                                                case '/':
                                                        while (_next() && ch != '\n' && ch != '\r') {}
                                                        break;
                                                case '*':
                                                        _next();
                                                        for (;;) {
                                                                if (ch) {
                                                                        if (ch == '*') {
                                                                                if (_next() == '/') {
                                                                                        _next();
                                                                                        break;
                                                                                }
                                                                        } else {
                                                                                _next();
                                                                        }
                                                                } else {
                                                                        _error("Unterminated comment");
                                                                }
                                                        }
                                                        break;
                                                default:
                                                        _error("Syntax error");
                                        }
                                } else {
                                        break;
                                }
                        }
                }

                var _string:Function = function() {
                        var i, s = '', t, u;
            var outer:Boolean = false;

                        if (ch == '"') {
                while (_next()) {
                                        if (ch == '"') {
                                                _next();
                                                return s;
                                        } else if (ch == '\\') {
                                                switch (_next()) {
                                                case 'b':
                                                        s += '\b';
                                                        break;
                                                case 'f':
                                                        s += '\f';
                                                        break;
                                                case 'n':
                                                        s += '\n';
                                                        break;
                                                case 'r':
                                                        s += '\r';
                                                        break;
                                                case 't':
                                                        s += '\t';
                                                        break;
                                                case 'u':
                                                        u = 0;
                                                        for (i = 0; i < 4; i += 1) {
                                                                t = parseInt(_next(), 16);
                                                                if (!isFinite(t)) {
                                                                        outer = true;
                                    break;
                                                                }
                                                                u = u * 16 + t;
                                                        }
                            if(outer) {
                                outer = false;
                                break;
                            }
                                                        s += String.fromCharCode(u);
                                                        break;
                                                default:
                                                        s += ch;
                                                }
                                        } else {
                                                s += ch;
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                        _error("Bad string");
                }

                var _array:Function = function() {
                        var a = [];

                        if (ch == '[') {
                                _next();
                                _white();
                                if (ch == ']') {
                                        _next();
                                        return a;
                                }
                                while (ch) {
                                        a.push(_value());
                                        _white();
                                        if (ch == ']') {
                                                _next();
                                                return a;
                                        } else if (ch != ',') {
                                                break;
                                        }
                                        _next();
                                        _white();
                                }
                        }
                        _error("Bad array");
                }

                var _object:Function = function() {
                        var k, o = {};

                        if (ch == '{') {
                                _next();
                                _white();
                                if (ch == '}') {
                                        _next();
                                        return o;
                                }
                                while (ch) {
                                        k = _string();
                                        _white();
                                        if (ch != ':') {
                                                break;
                                        }
                                        _next();
                                        o[k] = _value();
                                        _white();
                                        if (ch == '}') {
                                                _next();
                                                return o;
                                        } else if (ch != ',') {
                                                break;
                                        }
                                        _next();
                                        _white();
                                }
                        }
                        _error("Bad object");
                }

                var _number:Function = function() {
                        var n = '', v;

                        if (ch == '-') {
                                n = '-';
                                _next();
                        }
                        while (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9') {
                                n += ch;
                                _next();
                        }
                        if (ch == '.') {
                                n += '.';
                                while (_next() && ch >= '0' && ch <= '9') {
                                        n += ch;
                                }
                        }
                        //v = +n;
            v = 1 * n;
                        if (!isFinite(v)) {
                                _error("Bad number");
                        } else {
                                return v;
                        }
                }

                var _word:Function = function() {
                        switch (ch) {
                                case 't':
                                        if (_next() == 'r' && _next() == 'u' && _next() == 'e') {
                                                _next();
                                                return true;
                                        }
                                        break;
                                case 'f':
                                        if (_next() == 'a' && _next() == 'l' && _next() == 's' &&
                                                        _next() == 'e') {
                                                _next();
                                                return false;
                                        }
                                        break;
                                case 'n':
                                        if (_next() == 'u' && _next() == 'l' && _next() == 'l') {
                                                _next();
                                                return null;
                                        }
                                        break;
                        }
                        _error("Syntax error");
                }

                _value = function() {
                        _white();
                        switch (ch) {
                                case '{':
                                        return _object();
                                case '[':
                                        return _array();
                                case '"':
                                        return _string();
                                case '-':
                                        return _number();
                                default:
                                        return ch >= '0' && ch <= '9' ? _number() : _word();
                        }
                }

                return _value();
        }
}
```

I want it to return "John", why doesnt it? Unfortunately i can't seem to find much documentation on this :(

Comment: Looks correct. Try a simpler object and see.

Comment: Hmmm, haven't used as2.0 in a long time, but far as I remember it has the eval() function, just like javascript, so you should be able to use eval to convert the loaded json string to an object

Comment: do a for(var i in o) to see what you do have.

Comment: Turns out i've just forgot to add JSON.as to the right folder :S
Have one other issue though... if i do trace before parsing my JSON-file, it returns correct, but after parsing it returns "[object Object]"...

Comment: That is how an object is shown by `trace`.

Comment: But that makes my application browser dependent, right?

Comment: Oh, and even if i do trace("gjgfhkgf") it returns object object if the parser ran before calling it...

Comment: @AntonGildebrand at least write an answer describing how exactly you fixed the problem? where should I put the JSON.as ?